# Ubuntu will not restart fully

Tags: 13.04, reboot, restart

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 on one of my hard drives: /dev/sdc I created a swap area partition (2 gigs) and two 250 gig partitions for root and /home respectively. Installation went flawlessly but after trying to reboot and boot into Win7 I noticed that Ubuntu would not fully restart. It closes the system and turns off feed to the monitors but the computer stays on and doesn't reset.

Comment: If you use `sudo reboot` from terminal, will it restart correctly?

Comment: Attempting now. Thanks for the fast response. Will report back.

Comment: Yes.. It restarted with no issues. Is there anything I can do to fix the UI reboot or will I need to use the terminal to restart indefinitely?